# Make a dictionary containing a list of dictionaries?

Tags: c#

How can I use this pattern to make a dictionary with list of dictionaries?

This works:

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> someDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "someKey" , new List<string> { "listValue1", "listValue2" } },
};
```

This doesn't work:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> whateverName = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>
    {
        { "someKey", new List<Dictionary<string, string>> { { "key1", "value1"}, { "key2", "value2"} } },
    };
```

"No overload for method takes two values"

Comment: Why is this downvoted? He asked a question and posted his code. He had a syntax error that two people pointed out in their answers. Seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> whateverName = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>
{

    { "someKey", new List<Dictionary<string, string>> { new Dictionary<string, string>{{ "key1", "value1"}, { "key2", "value2"} } } },
};
```

You were missing the point that you have a `List` of `Dictionary`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `Dictionary<string, string>` collection in  `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` list instead of `key` and `value`

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> whateverName = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>
{
    { "someKey",
         new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
         {
             new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                 { "key1", "value1"},
                 { "key2", "value2"}
             }
         }
    }
};
```